# Spring-orm 4.3.11 & Hibernate 5.0.10 - NoSuchMethodError: query.Query & classic.Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In our project we're upgrading technologies like spring, hibernate etc.., i'm using spring 4.3.11 with Hibernate 5.0.10. i'm experiencing the following issues throughout my project.

**Issue 1:**

```
Query query = (Query) getCurrentSession().createQuery("select SEQ_NEW.nextval from dual");
    final List findByNamedQuery = query.list();
```

this statement is throwing

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/Query;
```

I'm AutoWiring SessionFactory from hibernate 5 in my pojo

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class ServiceDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session getCurrentSession() {
        return this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    } 
}
```

Spring-Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>DB_SRC_WFY</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />  

    <bean id="TransDaoImpl"
        class="com.services.transactionservice.dao.impl.TransDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Transaction.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
                <prop key="jta.UserTransaction">java:jboss/UserTransaction</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Issue 2:**

when this method is executed,

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobInstance;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameter;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobLocator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobParametersNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class QuartzJobLauncher extends QuartzJobBean
{
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobLocator jobLocator;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private Map<String, String> jobParameters;
    public static final String JOB_NAME = "jobName";

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
        {
            Map<String, Object> jobDataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
            String jobName = (String) jobDataMap.get(JOB_NAME);
            try
            {

                //merged with ANID - start
                log.debug("job name >>" + jobName);
                Job job = null;
                if (null != jobName) 
                {
                    job = jobLocator.getJob(jobName);
                }
                else
                {
                    job = jobLocator.getJob("FaultRecovery");
                }
                //merged with ANID - end

                JobParameters allParams = translateParams(job, jobParameters);            
                jobLauncher.run(job, allParams);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.error("Could not execute job.", e);
            }
        }
}
```

It throws

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.createQuery(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:152)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.readPage(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernatePagingItemReader.doReadPage(HibernatePagingItemReader.java:167)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:107)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:103)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:68)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:262)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:248)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
        at QuartzJobLauncher.executeInternal(QuartzJobLauncher.java:62)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

while executing `jobLauncher.run(job, allParams);`

I think these issues are related to each other. When i went through similar posts they were about using spring 4 with hibernate 5.2 and they specified to use hibernate 5.1 or 5.0. i'm using hibernate 5.0 but still i'm experiencing these issues.

**Note:** This exact code was running properly with spring 3 and hibernate 3.

This is my module.xml from wildfly 10.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source. ~ Copyright 2011, Red Hat, 
    Inc., and individual contributors ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See 
    the copyright.txt file in the ~ distribution for a full listing of individual 
    contributors. ~ ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify 
    it ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as ~ published 
    by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of ~ the License, or 
    (at your option) any later version. ~ ~ This software is distributed in the 
    hope that it will be useful, ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the 
    implied warranty of ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 
    See the GNU ~ Lesser General Public License for more details. ~ ~ You should 
    have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public ~ License along with 
    this software; if not, write to the Free ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 
    Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: 
    http://www.fsf.org. -->

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="dependencies">

    <dependencies>


        <module name="javax.api" />
        <!-- <module name="org.apache.ws.security" /> -->
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
        <module name="javax.xml.soap.api" />
        <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
        <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true"/>  
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
        <module name="javax.jms.api" />
        <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" export="true"/> 
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="sun.jdk" />
        <module name="sqlserver.jdbc" />
        <module name="com.unisys.leida.framework.services" />
        <module name="com.unisys.leida.framework.runtime" />
        <module name="com.unisys.leida.framework.lsb" />

    </dependencies>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="acegi-security-1.0.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="activation-1.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="antlr-2.7.6.jar" />
        <resource-root path="antlr-3.3.jar" />
        <resource-root path="antlr-runtime-3.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="aspectjrt-1.6.12.jar" />
        <resource-root path="AssureID-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="activemq-client-5.10.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="aware-pivPack-jni-2.0.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="aware-preface-jni-4.0.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="aware-xm-1.3.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="axiom-api-1.2.9.jar" />
        <resource-root path="axiom-impl-1.2.9.jar" />
        <resource-root path="axis-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-bridge-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-css-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-dom-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-ext-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-gui-util-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-gvt-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-parser-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-script-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-svg-dom-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-util-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="batik-xml-1.6-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="barcode4j-2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="bcprov-jdk16-140.jar" />
        <resource-root path="bsh-2.0b4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="castor-1.3.jar" />
        <resource-root path="ckez-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="comm-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-codec-1.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-collections-3.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-compress-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-dbcp-20030825.184428.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-exec-1.0.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-fileupload-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-io-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-io-2.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-lang-2.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-net-2.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-pool-20030825.183949.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-digester-1.7.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="dom4j-1.6.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="drools-compiler-5.3.1.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="drools-core-5.3.1.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="drools-persistence-jpa-5.3.1.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="ecj-3.5.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="EPIBuilder_jni-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="ezjcom-1.8.jar" />
        <resource-root path="fckez-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="Filters-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="flexjson-2.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="fmcojapi-1.3.jar" />
        <resource-root path="Fraud_Schema-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="freemarker-2.3.15.jar" />
        <resource-root path="geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar" />
        <resource-root path="groovy-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.10.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="hornetq-core-2.2.2.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="icu4j-2.6.1.jar" />        
        <resource-root path="itext-2.1.7.jar" />        
        <resource-root path="jai_codec-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jasperreports-4.0.1.jar" />        
        <resource-root path="jai_core-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jai_imageio-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="JAssureIDCOMPlatformSDK-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jasypt-1.9.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="javassist-3.10.0.GA.jar" />
        <resource-root path="javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jaxen-1.2.0-atlassian-2.jar" />
        <!-- <resource-root path="jaxrpc-1.0.jar" /> -->
        <resource-root path="jboss-seam-2.2.2.Final.jar" />
        <!-- <resource-root path="jbpm-bam-5.5.0.Final.jar" /> -->
        <resource-root path="jbpm-bpmn2-5.2.0.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jbpm-flow-5.2.0.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jbpm-flow-builder-5.2.0.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jbpm-human-task-5.2.0.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jbpm-jpdl-3.3.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jbpm-persistence-jpa-5.2.0.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jbpm-workitems-5.2.0.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jdom-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jnbcore-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="JPerson-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="junit-4.11.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jython-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="knowledge-api-5.3.1.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="L1ID_API-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="mail-1.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="milyn-smooks-all-1.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="mvel2-2.1.RC1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="opencsv-1.7.jar" />
        <resource-root path="oro-2.0.8.jar" />
        <resource-root path="PageScanApi-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="persistence-api-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="PtkSdk-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="rome-0.9.jar" />
        <resource-root path="slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="smack-3.0.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-batch-admin-manager-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-batch-admin-resources-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-batch-integration-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-batch-test-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar" /> 
        <resource-root path="spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" /> <!-- pavan -->                                                          
        <resource-root path="spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-context-support-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-expression-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-integration-file-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-integration-ftp-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-integration-http-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-integration-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-integration-jmx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-integration-mail-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-jdbc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-jms-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-mock-2.0.8.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-oxm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-remoting-2.0-m2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-security-crypto-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-support-2.0-m2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-ws-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-ws-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="spring-xml-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc4-3.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="stringtemplate-3.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="WSQUtil-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="wss4j-1.5.8.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xdb-6.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xmlsec-1.4.3.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xmlsec-2.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xom-1.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xstream-1.3.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zcommon-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zel-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zhtml-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zk-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zkbind-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zkplus-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zul-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zweb-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="zweb-6.5.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="json-simple-1.1.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="commons-httpclient-3.1.jar" />

        <resource-root path="jbossts-common-jbossts-common.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jbossjta-4.2.2.GA.jar" />
        <resource-root path="concurrent-1.3.4.jar" />
        <resource-root path="cglib-2.2.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jettison-1.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="quartz-2.2.1.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="classmate-1.3.0.jar" />
        <resource-root path="jasypt-hibernate5-1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
        <resource-root path="hibernate-infinispan-5.0.10.Final.jar" />
        <resource-root path="xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar" />

    </resources>

</module>
```

Comment: what `SEQ_NEW.nextval` return?

Comment: sorry for silly asking, but, are you sure that right jars are in the classpath? Maybe some old jar is still loaded?

Comment: @YCF_L `SEQ_NEW.nextval` returns a integer value like 3001

Comment: @gtosto i have appended my dependencies list

Comment: then try with `final List<Integer> findByNamedQuery = query.list();`

Comment: @YCF_L the issue seems to be with this line `Query query = (Query) getCurrentSession().createQuery("select SEQ_NEW.nextval from dual");`

Comment: i don't know why you use cast `(Query)` why not using sessionFactory to get getCurrentSession `Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSqlQuery("select SEQ_NEW.nextval from dual");`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue!!!
turns out i was building the code on hibernate 5.2.x and during runtime i downgraded it. Once i rebuilt it with hibernate 5.0.10 it worked.